# React Hooks Const Component vs Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I understand the difference between a functional component and a class component, but what's the difference between const component to a functional component?

e.g

```
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div>Home</div>
    )
}
```

To

```
function Home() {
     return (
        <div>Home</div>
    )
}
```

Both of them can use hooks, so what's the main difference?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no effective difference. First is creating a function using [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
syntax and storing it to a constant and the second is creating a plain function.

Both are functions that will perform the exact same task, return the component JSX code for rendering.

Also, there is no such term nor concept *"Const Component"*; there are *"Functional Components"* and *"Class Components"*.

Comment: I assume I didn't have the words to define it but my intention was for a declared function that returns JSX, thanks for correction. But is there any specific reason that I'll want to assign the arrow function into a constant or it doesn't really matter?

Comment: There is a major difference between those two implementation, and that's the `this`, `arguments` and `super` scope and implementation, it's not just syntactic sugar. I suggest you read the mozilla wiki page that I include in my answer and also read this Q/A [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361380/1889685). **BUT** in a case of defining a component there is actually **no effective difference**.

Comment: Yes I know that, my question was referring to hooks because there is no use of 'this' and 'super'. I didn't understand the difference in hooks (with components, unlike handling events which I use a constant as a reference) because both of them can use hooks but I guess it doesn't really matter... thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

One (the biggest?) practical difference is that JavaScript functions are [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) but constants, for practical purposes, are not. Thus it is possible to use a function before it is declared:

```
const App = () => (
  <>
    <MyComponent />
  </>
)
function MyComponent() {}
```

But if you replace the MyComponent declaration with

```
const MyComponent = () => {}
```

The code will not work, until you move the component declaration up so the component is declared and initialized *before* it is used.

I liked [this](https://dev.to/ugglr/react-functional-components-const-vs-function-2kj9) explanation. It's practical and to-the-point.