# Can you re-use React elements across different renders and contexts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a component like this:

```js
const Foo = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  </div>
)
```

Note that it doesn't take any props; it returns the same JSX on every render

Could this be used as just a constant instead of a function?

```js
const Foo = (
  <div>
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
  </div>
)
```

or will React have problems re-using the *exact* same `React.createElement()` result across re-renders and - more likely - in different DOM contexts throughout the app?

```js
const OtherComponent = ({ ... }) => (
  <div>
    {Foo}
    {...}
  </div>
)

const OtherOtherComponent = ({ ... }) => (
  <span>
    {Foo}
  </span>
)
```

EDIT: It crossed my mind that any hooks getting called inside child components are probably going to get messed up by this, so it's probably a bad idea.

EDIT 2: Disregard the first "EDIT"; I tested it out and was surprised to find that a hook buried under the const react-node does actually get called multiple times. I'm leaning towards thinking this is indeed safe, but would still like confirmation from someone more familiar with React's internals.

[image: Using hook within constant node]

Comment: You can do that fine, it's just when you use it instead of `<Foo/>` it's doing to be `{Foo}`

Comment: You're right about the syntax; I adjusted my sample code to match. However the question remains of whether or not this is reliably safe behavior.

Comment: It's totally safe, it boils down to taste and preference. The perf difference is probably negligible.

Comment: The JSX is just a template for `React.createElement` to create as many DOM elements as it need be.

Comment: Anyway, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/61293107/34586

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The question you link is using a const arrow function; my example is just a const holding a JSX expression (`React.createElement` result, as you note). The same question could be asked of the above replacing the JSX expressions with `React.createElement()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can use the just jsx assigned to a variable, if there are no complex stuff.
[Ref: for acknowledge](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component)

Updated with the POC:
[image]

Comment: It's interesting that they do this in an official example, though it still doesn't give me firm confirmation of the underlying question: is it safe to use this value in multiple places? In the example, it's implied that the `const` is only being used once.

Comment: As a pure code it will works the same. [Try it out here](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?presets=react&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwKYBt1wBQEpEDeAUIogE6pQhlIA8AJjAG4B8AEhlogO5xnr0AhLQD0jVgG4iAXyJA)

Answer (score 0):

This is just javascript. In first case, you create an object whose reference is not changed if you keep using it again and again.

In the other case its a function and everytime it is invoked, a new instance/object is returned.

A demonstration of the same,

```js
const Comp1 = <div>Comp 1</div>;

const Comp2 = () => {
  console.log('rendering comp 2' + Math.random());
  return  <div>Comp 2</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const obj1 = Comp1;
  const obj2 = Comp1;
  const obj3 = Comp1;

  console.log(Object.is(obj1, Comp1));
  console.log(Object.is(obj1, obj2));

  console.log(Object.is(obj2, Comp1));
  console.log(Object.is(obj2, obj3));

  return (
    <div>
      {obj1}
      {obj2}
      {obj3}
      <Comp2/>
      <Comp2/>
      <Comp2/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It's not just about JavaScript, because the object held in the `const` is potentially mutable. The question is whether or not React mutates it once it's been handed off.